mgt-chat and mgt-new-chat see undefined globalProvider
Following the excellent Graph Toolkit with React (including Chat) sample:
everything works except the chat. NewChat gives me the unexpected error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
    at getCurrentUser (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111398:107)
    at currentUserId (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111399:29)

which indicates that Providers.globalProvider is 'undefined'.
Calling createNewChat gave me:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')
    at createChatThread (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111060:28)
    at createNewChat (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:111371:86)

I'm using
Providers.globalProvider = new Msal2Provider({
  clientId: '<my client id>',
  scopes: ['calendars.read', 'user.read', 'openid', 'profile', 'people.read', 'user.readbasic.all', ...allChatScopes],
});

in index.tsx, and
"@microsoft/mgt-element": "next.mgt-chat",
"@microsoft/mgt-msal2-provider": "next.mgt-chat",
"@microsoft/mgt-react": "next.mgt-chat",
"@microsoft/mgt-chat": "next.mgt-chat",

in package.json.
What's missing?
